# SQL Insert many value 1 time or loop Insert each value many time which one is better?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 )   
VALUES ( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 ),(..,..),(Value n,Value n)
```

or

```
Loop 
{INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 )   
VALUES ( Value1, Value2 )}
```

which one is better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on how many values you're actually inserting.

Multi-row insert *can* have advantages if there are a lot of rows since you're not having to do a lot of round-trip calls to the database, something that can be important if your client and your DBMS are thousands of kilometers from each other.

For only a few rows, or if your client/DBMS are co-located, you may find there's not a lot of difference.

Comment: How about 50000 row , Which way should I use ? From your answer I think Multi-row , right ?

Comment: @crazyoxygen, yes, that's one of the situations I would use multi-row insert for, though not all 50K at once since that would be a rather large SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

As you put lots of record in one sql, you might need to check the global config `max_allowed_packet` of your MySQL server, make sure the sql length won't longer than the`max_allowed_packet` or you can set it to a larger value.

Answer (score 1):

Use multi rows when you inserting 50 000 rows. Don't forget to split it a little.
Maybe 50 querys. 1 000 rows for each query.
This will reduce the load of your DB a little.
Only split it when its a heavy loaded production db. 
If there are no other querys, throw all 50 000 querys in 1 query in your DB.

As mentioned already, don't forget to change the max_allowed_packet or you will have db errors soon.